# Getting rows which contain certain value in a column per each group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, int, data-cleaning, isnull

was wondering if you could provide some guidance with this one- I'm still working on [this data](http://data.un.org/Data.aspx?d=EDATA&f=cmID:ES&c=2,5,6,7,8&s=_crEngNameOrderBy:asc,_enID:asc,yr:desc&v=1)and here's what I am trying to do:
-For each grouped 'country or area', I am trying to get the rows that contain the 2016 'quantity' and the 2011 'quantity'. However, it looks like there may be some countries that don't have a row for 2016 or 2011. The problem is I get an error when executing the following code:

```
for c in grp['Country or Area'].unique():
  deltafiveyrs.append(grp[(grp['Year'] == 2016.0) & (grp['Country or Area'] == c)]['Quantity'] -  grp[(grp['Year'] == 2011.0) & (grp['Country or Area'] == c)]['Quantity'])
```

The error message I get is:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:5: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  """
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-90579ab30ed1> in <module>()
      3 
      4 for c in grp['Country or Area'].unique():
----> 5   deltafiveyrs.append(grp[(grp['Year'] == 2016.0) & (grp['Country or Area'] == c)]['Quantity'] -  grp[(grp['Year'] == 2011.0) & (grp['Country or Area'] == c)]['Quantity'])
      6 
      7 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/base.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    266         else:
    267             if key not in self.obj:
--> 268                 raise KeyError("Column not found: {key}".format(key=key))
    269             return self._gotitem(key, ndim=1)
    270 

KeyError: 'Column not found: False'
```

does anybody know what is going on? Should the values in the 'years' column be changed from float to int? And what would be the best way on how to handle the groups with no values for 2011/2016?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Explore and Clean the data before working on that.
few columns (ignoring Quantity footnotes) are having nan values. so lets drop those rows and proceed further. I tried this in jupyter notebook which gave dataframe of countries with quantity in year 2011 & 2016.

```
cdf = df[['Country or Area', 'Commodity - Transaction', 'Year', 'Unit', 'Quantity']]
cdf.dropna()
cdf[(cdf['Year']== 2011) | (cdf['Year']== 2016)]
```